# Местоимение "она" в творительном / дательном падеже

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, грамматика, склонение, выбор-слов

> Вокруг жила История. Ей можно было дышать. Ей нужно было просто
>   открыть свое сердце.

Как выйти из положения, если автор дорожит симметрией начал предложений, а первое "ей" может быть прочитано как КОМУ, а не КЕМ/ЧЕМ?

Может, я придираюсь?

Comment: Может, замените на "ею"?

Comment: Я заменяла - автору не понравилось.

Comment: Мое субъективное мнение. Первое (мгновенное) восприятие - именно такое, как хочет автор. Начинаешь задумываться - получается, что обе фразы не однозначны. Мне начинает казаться, что историей нужно открывать свое сердце, как штопором открывают бутылку вина. Заменить первое "ей" на "ею" - некоторое улучшение. Но раз автор не согласен, то можно оставить все как есть. Ничего другого мне в голову не приходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если автору так необходима анафора, пусть останется так, ничего страшного, по-моему, всё понятно. Если кто-то прочитает как  Д. п. (но это надо очень постараться), пусть будет так, читатель ведь имеет право на своё в*и*дение, он ведь в какой-то степени соавтор.

Можно анафору усилить повтором, тогда уберётся неясность с падежами:

*Вокруг жила История. Историей можно было дышать. Истории нужно было просто открыть свое сердце.*

Comment: Неясность исчезла, а вместе с ней и обаяние (шарм).

Comment: М_Г, тут самое ценное, что "ничего страшного" в авторском варианте. Но как читатель я споткнулась.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы первое "ей" не было прочитано как КОМУ (Д.п.), а нужно КЕМ/ЧЕМ (Т.п.) нужно употребить форму "ею".

Comment: Но я же указываю: автор дорожит симметрией...

Answer (score 0):

Форма "ей" в творительном падеже это новояз и является разговорной формой, а не литературной. Это также неправильно, неграмотно,  как и "разрешенное" с недавних пор "кофе - оно" вместо "кофе - он". Это ухудшает литературный русский язык, приближает его к неграмотной разговорной речи.  "Ею" - это единственно правильный вариант для творительного падежа, отвечает на вопрос "кем". "Ей" - это дательный падеж и отвечает на вопрос "кому".

Comment: Важны только примеры и ссылки по теме вопроса. Причём здесь разрешенное кофе?